# sum up multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

I had query 2 in array form:

result1:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=5)
      'total' => string '100' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '2' (length=5)
      'total' => string '200' (length=18)
```

result2:

```
 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=5)
      'payment' => string '101' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '2' (length=5)
      'payment' => string '102' (length=5)
```

I was merge these two arrays into 1 using `array_merge`

```
$a_m = array_merge($result,$result2);
        foreach ($a_m as $value) {
            $group[$value['uid']][] = $value;
        }
```

SO, the array now group by the uid

output:

```
1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'uid' => string '1' (length=5)
          'total' => string '100' (length=17)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'uid' => string '1' (length=5)
          'payment' => string '101' (length=7)
2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'uid' => string '2' (length=5)
          'total' => string '200' (length=17)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'uid' => string '2' (length=5)
          'payment' => string '201' (length=7)
```

SO, now I need to sum up the `payment` and `total` according to the `uid`.
I met problem on how can I get the `payment` and `total` in array can sum up these two value?

```
$total_value = $payment + $total;
```

I need the result of like this(I am not sure the form of result as I only need to sum up the value first)

```
0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '1' (length=5)
      'total_value' => string '201' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'uid' => string '2' (length=5)
      'total_value' => string '402' (length=18)
```

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: `$value[0]['total'] + $value[1][payment']` ? Not very dynamic if order change or key is missing so add some `if (isset...)` or `if (!empty...)` for each key maybe ?

Comment: Do you want to sum the `total` and `payment` of each array element of for all the array together?

Comment: @M.Hemant I stuck at the array result I shared.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm i edited my post hope you could understand it...

Comment: @dWinder yes because now it is group by the id now and i need to sum up in each id inside the second array

Comment: So your desire output make no sense - both element has `id` of `1` and the keys are different and also the value are just example and not fit. Can you please edit the question and have understood-able desire output?

Comment: @beginner From where you got these numbers `123` and `456` "expected output" means exactly how you want to look the result

Comment: I had edit the post now, sorry for inconvenience ;). thanks for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why there is 123 and 456 in the example, but to get the result for 'total' + 'payment' and if there are always 2 arrays, 1 for the total and 1 for the payment, one option could be to use array_map.

In the example I use `$array`, but in your code that would be `$group[$value['uid']]`.

```
$result = array_map(function($x) {
    return  ['uid' => $x[0]['uid'], 'total_value' => (float)($x[0]['total']) + (float)($x[1]['payment'])];
}, $arrays);

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [total_value] => 201
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [total_value] => 401
        )

)
```

[PHp demo](https://3v4l.org/08kBu)

Comment: @dWinder You are right,  apart from the 123 and 456 I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird so i need change the $arrays to $group[$value['uid']?  it will come out undefined offset 0

Comment: Isn't your current output from `$a_m`? Then you could use that instead of `$arrays`

Comment: currently working it, now need to isset the value if 'total' are not available